# Does anyone has idea what DR abbreviation in car name means?

Tags: ford, focus

I'm looking for a car and found a really nice one, but the description says:

**Ford Focus 1.8 5dr DR OWNED HISTORY**

Does anyone has an idea what DR OWNED means? Is it "Doctor owned" or "Drowned"? Or could it be something else? I dont mind buying a doctor owned car :) The description says nothing about drowned car.

If this helps, this is in UK.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping assistance

Comment: Please feel free to bring off-topic questions such as these [to the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/motor-vehicle-maintenance-and-repair).  You'll likely get more useful information without the stricter Q&A requirements of the main site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent about 20 minutes searching and supposedly it's a fairly common thing in the UK to advertise the fact that the car in question is/was owned by a doctor. Probably just a bit of vanity on the part of the seller as there's no reason that a doctor would treat his car any better than a lawyer or businessman. In fact, there is a thing called the "doctor test" that manufacturers perform on their cars to see how well they cope with questionable treatment, e.g. constant stopping and starting. So "DR OWNED" may actually show that the car's engine wasn't well looked after, even if the interior is immaculate.

Comment: You were indeed right, i rang the owner and it was doctor owned. I will give it a try and see how test drive goes. Its lovely looking car, but as suggested - will take extra look at the engine